# write struct into a char array using memcpy in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memcpy

I am learning to do the memory management in c++.
Assume I have a char array in c++

```
char **arr = new char*[16];
for (int i = 0; i<8; i ++) {
    arr[i] = new char[64];
}
```

each block now is 64 bytes big.

The first index of the array (first block) is reserved for a integer array, e.g. int A[16]. 
I will need to A[16] into the first, so I use the following code:

```
memcpy(arr[0], &A, 8);
```

Then I need put Struct information into the char array.

```
struct Person{
    char name[3];
    int age;
    int s_id;
    int ssn;
};
```

now this struct is 16 bytes, I can put 4 Person object in one block into the array.

But the problem is, how can I achieve it by using memory copy? I know how to do integers, but I don't know how to store struct into a char array.

I thought it would be easier to put these structs into a array of struts and then copy into in array.

```
Person* person = new Person[4];
memcpy(arr[1], person, 64);
```

but this code crushes, I believe is memory problem, but the debugger say nothing about it.
I guess I am not allocating memory contiguously so I am not using memcpy correctly?

Comment: This smells of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/137574). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is `arr` in the final example? If it's the same double-pointer as the first, then you probably meant `arr[something]`, to write to one of the arrays, not `arr` to overwrite the pointers themselves.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will go a long way in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: its like Barry said. your memory is not in arr, it is in arr[x].

Comment: This is not a good example of memory management in C++. At all. You are learning incorrectly!!

Comment: Your program should not rely on the fact that `sizeof(Person) == 16`.  It might be with the current implementation you've tested but it might be different if you compile it elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with @JerryCoffin.  Seems like a serialization problem.  There are better ways to handle it than memcpy.  It might be better for you to describe what you're trying to solve in broader terms than this specific implementation.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, learn about std::vector. There is almost no use for the array new that you use.

Answer (score 1):

I think here:

```
memcpy(arr, person, 64);
```

You probably meant to copy it into the first buffer:

```
memcpy(arr[0], person, 64);
```

Since `arr` is `char**`, the first line is going to override your *pointers*, rather than copy data into one of the character buffers.

Comment: exactly. you have multiple "zones" of 64 length, therefore you need to pick one to copy to. arr is just a pointer so you cannot write something length 64 over it without breaking something.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it, but the problem is still there, the code cannot run

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on an array of size N having size that is N times the size of its element type.

You should not rely on the sizes of your various types. Use sizeof(). Although sizeof(char) is defined to be (sizeof_t) 1.

You cannot rely on the size of a record being the size of the sum of its fields. Extra bytes may be inserted for alignment of certain types to certain multiples of addresses. Eg probably after a char[3] field. Eg even at the end so that in arrays of the record type it is properly aligned after another one of itself.

The `new` returns "a pointer to N objects" ie "a pointer to the start of an array of N objects", ie the address of the first of a block of N objects.

```
Person* pperson4 = new Person[4];
Person person;
Person person4[4];

// one of these
char *parr = new char[4*sizeof(Person)];
char *parr = new char[4*sizeof(person)];
char *parr = new char[sizeof(Person[4])];
char *parr = new char[sizeof(person4)];

// one of these
char arr[4*sizeof(Person)];
char arr[4*sizeof(person)];
char arr[sizeof(Person[4])];
char arr[sizeof(person4)];

/*
destination argument is parr or &arr[0] or arr or &arr
source argument is either
    pperson4 or &person4[0] as address of 1st of 4 objects sizeof(Person)
    &person4 or person4 as address of 1 object sizeof(person4)
length argument is one of
    sizeof(person4), sizeof(Person[4]), 4*sizeof(Person), 4*sizeof(person)
*/

// thus any of these etc
memcpy(parr, pperson4, 4*sizeof(Person);
memcpy(parr, pperson4, sizeof(Person[4]));
memcpy(parr, person4, sizeof(person4);
memcpy(arr, pperson4, 4*sizeof(person));
memcpy(&arr, &person4, sizeof(Person[4]));
memcpy(&arr[0], &person4[0], sizeof(person4));
```

(Learn how arguments are treated when passing values for parameters declared as pointers, as arrays and as references.)